# Web database application architecture

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-2, architecture

There is a medium size database application that needs to be built featuring a web interface. The platform is asp.net 3.5 (asp.net mvc 2), sql server and ext.net 1.3.0. The tool is visual studio 2010.

I wonder, should I start with the database design and business logic and move on to the UI when I've a complete working draft/skeleton? Or should I build the database and BL step by step and bind them to the web UI as I progress?

Even more specifically, should I construct the whole BL functionality as a separate dll project and then have it referenced by the web application project? If so, what communication options do I have? web services, for example?

Last but not least, the web application requires a security mechanism (user accounts etc). Should I design and integrate it right from the start or can I add it when everything else is ready?

(I hope my question is clear enough. As far as I know, creating a dozen or more aspx pages as a means of building and testing the application functionality leads to all shorts of problems and dead ends while being extremely time consuming. What I seek is a way to separate the UI from everything else. Something like having a working prototype to show case to the customer and have the (ext.net) web UI built later as a completely separate step.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a particular reason why you are not planning on using .NET 4.0 and MVC 3? MVC 3 comes with the razor view engine, which produces much nicer and cleaner views. And if you use .NET 4.0 you can use the Entity Framework. The new Entity Framework 4.3 lets you use code first with migrations, which might be a good way to go in a project where you need to "explore" the requirements in collaboration with the customer. Using code first you build your model using POCO classes and let EF take care of the database schema. This is effective if you make lots of changes to your model, which it sound like you might want to. Check out [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Visual-Studio-Toolbox-Entity-Framework-Part-2) video for a good introduction to code first with migrations.

Comment: The 1 and only reason is that I am confused enough with the architecture issues let alone using things I am not familiar with (.net 4, EF etc). Nevertheless, thank you very much for the link at least I know now what code first is all about.